# Add-in targeting modern document library does not support HostWebDialog="true"?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, custom-actions, office-365-developer

I am trying to make a SharePoint add-in work with the SharePoint Online "new experience". It adds a custom menu item custom action that runs inside iframe (HostWebDialog="true") and works well with SharePoint 2013:

```
<CustomAction Id="1237b974-6d89-4d20-b8ac-2b4ba8e21dce.MenuTest1"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="101"
                Location="EditControlBlock"
                Sequence="1"
                Title="Menu text"
                HostWebDialog="true"
                HostWebDialogHeight="280"
                HostWebDialogWidth="400">

    <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/MyPage.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}&amp;SPSource={Source}&amp;SPListURLDir={ListUrlDir}&amp;SPItemURL={ItemUrl}" />
  </CustomAction>
```

However with the "new experience" it does not work. No JS errors or any messages are displayed, the menu call is silently ignored.

Does the "new experience" support HostWebDialog="true" option?

Comment: I just tried and it's working fine for me.

Comment: The issue is in "New Experience" mode. In "Classic Experience" it works fine. Unfortunately http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com does not allow me to edit this quetion and clarify it.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? SharePoint 2016 doesn't have the new experience.

Comment: Yes, I am using SharePoint Online. Please note that in HTTP headers it reports this is a SharePoint 2016. It looks like it is somewhat different from a "real" SharePoint 2016.

Comment: That may be so but if you say SharePoint 2016, people will take it mean SharePoint Server 2016 on-premises. I edited your question to more properly describe the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Update on Modern Document Libraries and Extensibility](http://dev.office.com/blogs/update-on-modern-document-libraries-and-extensiblity) they should work.

> We’ve already made some good progress here.  Theming, global
>   navigation links, and URL-based custom actions that extend the ribbon
>   and context menus are already supported in the modern document library
>   experience.  This ensures that customers and partners taking advantage
>   of these features can use the modern document library experience
>   without compromising their customizations.

A couple weeks ago I tried to create an app with custom actions for a modern document library and I got the same results you did - they didn't work. I Googled for a while but I didn't find any solution to the problem.

**Update (Aug 1, 2016):**
I tried again today and I was able to get both types of custom actions (menu item and ribbon) working against a document library using the new experience. I wasn't able to get the target page to show in a dialog.

**Update 2 (Aug 1, 2016):**
I've been on an email thread with people from Microsoft and they have confirmed that opening the target page in a dialog is not supported in the new experience.

Comment: Could you please clarify, will HostWebDialog="true" work in future? This functionality is absolutely critical for us.

Comment: We need to trigger our custom web browser protocol: myprotocol:https://corp.sharepoint.com/file.ext. We can not specify protocol URL directly - our SPS add-in does not pass validation in this case. Specifying javascript: protocol does not pass validation too. Opening a new window/tab or SPS web dialog does not work either. I would greatly appreciate any solution to this.

Comment: A suggest you add the request for this functionality to the SharePoint User Voice (https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/). If enough people vote for your request there is a chance that Microsoft will add it.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the dialog parameters in your custom action , it will be translated into Javascript:LaunchApp(url, dialogoptions) with the new experience if the dialog options is not null it simply won't work and will cause a javascript error.

You should remove the dialog options and the url will open in a new window.

see full details on how custom actions works with the new doclib experience below:

http://www.sharepointtweaks.com/2016/07/new-document-library-experience-part-ii.html

Amr

**Update 1 Aug** after the 5th release of the odspo-next now the dialog opens in a new window and no javascript error is thrown

Comment: Did you try this? It does not work.